# How to connect hive to tableau?

Tags: hadoop, hive, tableau-api, bigdata

I have deployed a custom multi-node hadoop cluster with two slaves and one master and stored data in hive table. How can I connect hive to tableau for visualization?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: **1.** You connect Tableau to Hive, not the other way around. **2.** You need to start a HiveServer2 service **3.** you need a Hive ODBC driver, either from Cloudera or from HortonWorks **4.** you need a good deal of patience because Tableau is slooow *(common knowledge)* and uses a syntax that does not always work with Hive, and tries to manage a temp table which Hive does not support.

Comment: I am not using either of cloudera or hortonworks vm to create the multi node cluster. Instead I am using three centOS machines. Will these drivers work in my case?

Comment: Why don't you try out?? BTW, Horton prides itself in being an "Open Source" company so there is no reason its driver should not work (except for backwards compatibility issues, but these are the same whatever the distro).

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. I am not sure whether it was due to compatiblity issue or hiveserver2 not working. You can refer to this link for my hiveserver2 issue : [hiveserver2 issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853757/unable-to-start-hiveserver2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We Can not connect hive to tableau if we are using a custom multi node cluster. Available tableau-hive connectors are for packaged clusters like hortonworks, cloudera etc. only. We can use open source visualization tools like apache zeppelin or apache hue as an alternative to tableau.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes we can connect hive with tableau. first, install appropriate
   driver for your framework, for example if you are using Cloudera
   then install cloudera hive odbc driver, or for hortonworks you can
   install hortonworks hive odbc, this driver can work for other
   frameworks also.
2. Then go to the cmd line and type cmd:-
    hive --service hiveserver2 
      {this cmd may pop up issue messages, in that case check for the default 
      hive remote server for your framework}.
3. Then complete driver configuration of the installed driver.
4. Then, atlast, in Tableau go to more servers>>find your server>>and fill the required fields>>sign in.

For more help, check this https://acadgild.com/blog/connecting-hive-with-tableau/